# read song file and save as json

Tags: node.js, json, readfile

I am trying to read a file that has a song text with many sections. but for some reason i am not getting  the expected the result. can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.
I have provided the expected result, what I got instead, and the code. I want the function

- to be able to work on any file and songs with x amount of sections.
- I need to be able to call the function anywhere with the path to the song as parameter
- the function should read the song and return a json object with all the sections.

Expected result

```
{
  "songSections": [
    {
      "num": "1",
      "text": [
        "Vous qui sur la terre habitez, ",
        "Chantez à haute voix, chantez!",
        "Réjouissez-vous au Seigneur,",
        "Par un saint hymne à son honneur!"
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": [
        "N'est-il pas le Dieu souverain",
        "Qui nous a formés de sa main,",
        "Nous, le peuple qu'il veut chérir,",
        "Et le troupeau qu'il veut nourrir?"
      ],
      "num": "2"
    },
    {
      "text": [
        "Entrez dans son temple aujourd'hui;",
        "Venez vous présenter à lui,",
        "Célébrez son nom glorieux,",
        "Et l'élevez jusques aux cieux."
      ],
      "num": "3"
    },
    {
      "text": [
        "C'est un Dieu rempli de bonté,",
        "D'une éternelle vérité,",
        "Toujours propice à nos souhaits,",
        "Et sa grâce dure à jamais."
      ],
      "num": "4"
    }
  ],
  "Title": "001 - Vous, qui sur la terre habitez"
}
```

Getting this instead

```
{
  "songSections": [
    {
      "num": "1",
      "text": [
        "Vous qui sur la terre habitez, ",
        "Chantez à haute voix, chantez!",
        "Réjouissez-vous au Seigneur,",
        "Par un saint hymne à son honneur!"
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": [
        "N'est-il pas le Dieu souverain",
        "Qui nous a formés de sa main,",
        "Nous, le peuple qu'il veut chérir,",
        "Et le troupeau qu'il veut nourrir?"
      ],
      "num": "2"
    },
    {
      "text": [
        "Entrez dans son temple aujourd'hui;",
        "Venez vous présenter à lui,",
        "Célébrez son nom glorieux,",
        "Et l'élevez jusques aux cieux."
      ],
      "num": "3"
    }
  ],
  "Title": "001 - Vous, qui sur la terre habitez"
}
```

my code.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

async function processLineByLine(path) {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(path);

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });

  lineCount = 0
 
  let section = {num:'', text:[] }
  let song = { songSections:[ ] }
  let prev = 1

  for await (const line of rl) { 
        if(lineCount ==0)
            song.Title=line

      
        if(lineCount !=0 ){
          if(line ==='' ){
            // current section should be push to       songsections 
            song.songSections.push(section)
            //console.log(song) 
            prev = section.num;
            section ={text:[], num:''}
            console.log("Prev",prev)
          
          }else{
             if(isNaN(line)){
               section.text.push(line)
               // console.log(`section ${section.num}: ${line}`)
             }else{            
                            
               section.num  =line
               
             }
            
            
          }

          
        }

   
    
    lineCount++;
  
  }
 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(song));
  processLineByLine("song.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it seems to be missing only the **last section** of the file in the `JSON` object.

The text section being pushed into the `JSON` object when it encounters a blank line,

if the file that contains the song does not contain a blank line at the very end of the file,

the last section will not be pushed into it.

From what I understand from the function the song file should have a format like this:

```
{TITLE SONG}

1
{LINE TEXT}
{LINE TEXT}
{LINE TEXT}

2
{LINE TEXT}
{LINE TEXT}
```

Are you sure song file has a empty line at end ?

Comment: what do you suggest i do?  a space at the end of the files.

Comment: I suggest a empty line at end song files.
Because currently the function expect a empty line before push a new section inside the JSON object